# Tablelayout Scrolling and HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, scroll, tablelayout

I am having a problem with locating exactly where my scrolling will end up. I have a tablelayout (this particular one has one row and 35 columns). The tablelayout is inside a horizontalscrollview. I populate the row with an imageview all the same height, width and margin. I am using a dpad control to navigate the row. I have a view with an drawable back ground which is basically a box. The view is located where the first item of the tablelayout row appears. So when visible the first item is in the box. As I press the dpad right the row moves left to right with the current focused item moving to inside the box. Of course if I press the dpad left the row moves right to left. My problem is that I can't seem to get the row to scroll one image or column at a time. The first press I do get the column 1 but the next press I get a scroll to column 6. With each press the row scrolls but never one at a time. I have tried scrollto and scrollby each with no luck. I thought that I should be able to get the current scrollx position and just add the width of the child in the row but I am wrong. Can I get some guidance as to making the scroll move one column at a time? Thanks

```
popindex++;
TableRow row = (TableRow) mytable.getChildAt(0);  //GET ROW OF TABLE
int sx=row.getChildAt(popindex).getWidth();  //GET CHILD WIDTH IN ROW @ INDEX
mytable.scrollto(mytable.getScrollX()+sx, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, instead of using a scroll to get the desired effect, I opted to use setColumnCollapsed. I know it can be done with a scrolling effect but this works just as well for me. If somebody else runs into the same situation and wants to do it this way here is what I did.

```
List<Integer>colarray=new ArrayList<>();

index++;
colarray.add(index)
for(int i=0; i<colarray.size(),i++){
mytable.setColumnCollapsed(i, true)
}
```